# Intermittent network timeout on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 20.04, nginx

I've been having an intermittent network issue with my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server. Theres a few symptoms that seem to be similar but slightly different so I'm not sure where to look exactly.

Heres a list of the symptoms:

1. Nginx web server seems to have a 'start delay' - basically if I havent accessed the web page in awhile the first attempt will timeout, but after waiting 2-3 minutes after the first attempt it will load up fine almost like its sleeping until woken up (Should note, this Nginx implementation is running in a docker container)
2. ssh daemon is also seeming to have a timeout issue ESPECIALLY when accessed via LAN vs. public IP. When attempting to ssh into my server via LAN I will often get a `ssh: connect to host *.*.*.* port 22: No route to host` The only sure fire way I found to resolve this is to first ssh in using my public IP and then exit and retry with my LAN ip and it typically works. Additionally, many times while already connected, the connection will 'freeze up'/'timeout' so basically when I type nothing appears immediately but if I wait 2-3 minutes it will execute any keys pressed during the freeze(sshd is running on the system as a service, and I added `TCPKeepAlive yes` to the settings)

Theres a few more issues that are generally similar as the above two but I dont access them as often - for instance my elk stack reacts similarly to the nginx issue

Personally I think it may be something with the router settings, so if anyone knows something that may be funky with netgear gateway c7000v2 settings let me know (the only changes I made to factory is port forwarding).